# How to change URL on a magento extension?

Tags: php, magento, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to know how I can change the URL of my checkout cart. Whenever I continue to checkout or click on the checkout button, I get to the URL: mypage.com/onepagecheckout

I'm using this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout.html

The only way I got it working was making one rewrite and a redirect, one rewrite from "onepagecheckout" to "checkout" and another one permanent redirect from "onepagecheckout" to "checkout". I don't think this method is best practice, so I would like to know if there's a better option.

I tried going to the app/code/community/IWD/OnepaceCheckout/etc/config.xml and changed frontname to "checkout", but even that did not change anything.

Thanks for your time and help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the  in config.xml on both standard and admin.

Answer (score 3):

Please check in config.xml.here you found that  onepagecheckout
just change onepagecheckout according

```
 <frontend>
        <routers>
          .......
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>IWD_OnepaceCheckout/</module>
                    <frontName>onestepcheckout</frontName>
                </args>
           .......
        </routers>
```

also changed it `onestepcheckout.xml` accoding to you wish frontName